# Can we generalize this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

We have these identities :
$$x^{2n+1} + y^{2n+1} = (x+y)(x^{2n} - x^{2n-1}y + \cdots -y^{2n-1}x + y^{2n})$$
and
$$x^{2n+1} - y^{2n+1} = (x-y)(x^{2n} + x^{2n-1}y + \cdots + y^{2n-1}x + y^{2n})$$
If $n=1$ or $n=2$ , It is obvious that second parenthesis is non-negative .

For example for $n=1$ :

$x^2 - xy + y^2 \ge 0 \iff 2x^2 -2xy + 2y^2 \ge 0 \iff (x-y)^2 +x^2 + y^2 \ge 0 \iff \begin{cases} (x-y)^2 \ge 0 &  \\ x^2\ge0 \\ y^2 \ge 0  \end{cases} $

Can we prove that for all $n$ in these identities second parenthesis is non-negative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left side and the first term on the right will always have the same sign, so the second term on the right can't be negative.

**Edit** in response to comment asking for more details.

Since the function $x \mapsto x^{\text{odd}}$ is an increasing function the left side of the second equation has the same sign as the first term on the right.

For the first equation the assertion is obvious if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. If they have opposite signs then the signs are the same as the sign of whichever of $x$ and $y$ is further from $0$.

Comment: Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: How you can prove this expression ? "The left side and the first term on the right will always have the same sign"